# Replace failed HDD Raid 5 with different size

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hard-drive, hp, raid5, replace

One of the HDD on my server HP proliant DL 380 G7 failed, i have 6 hdd each 146gb sas 2.5 Hot plug.

Can i replace one HDD failed with larger size 450gb sas 2.5. Is the safe? And how the scenario for rebuild data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe but the disk will be added as a 146GB volume.

Comment: Is a need re config or the sistem rebuild automatically?

Comment: That would depend on your system configuration but it should if set up to handle hot swaps.

Comment: Handle hot swaps means? Can i directly replace when server and sistem still running

Comment: I don't know, that would depend on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely replace with a larger drive. In fact, HP started using 300GB disks to replace failed 146GB disks because manufacturers stopped producing 146GB drives.  But can you explain why you wouldn't just use the properly-sized disk? 146GB disks are still available on the used parts market.

Comment: I have find same size, because i very difflicult find on my country, order on ebay and amazon take to long time deliver. Thats way my plan replace with 450gb as the item is ready. So how its work for rebuild to new disk, need restart server or automatically rebuild

Comment: It is automatic. This is very basic hardware administration. You should understand how hot-swap disks work with hardware RAID.